# javascript regexp & extra characters in result

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, escaping

I want to find in a string substrings and replace them all. Substrings contain some special characters ($). I use regular expressions and get some (for me) unexpected results.

**Please tell me where my mistake.**

```
RegExp.escape = function(value) {
     return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

var str         = "[block $$text$$] ===";
var substr_old  = "[block $$text$$]";
var substr_new  = "[xxxxx $$text$$]";

console.log(str);

str = str.replace(RegExp(RegExp.escape(substr_old), 'g'), substr_new);

console.log(str);
```

results:

```
before: [block $$text$$] ===
after:  [xxxxx $text$] ===
```

**Why were $**?

I expect next result:

```
before: [block $$text$$] ===
after:  [xxxxx $$text$$] ===
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to use `$$` in the replacement pattern to replace with a single `$`.

Use

```
str = str.replace(RegExp(RegExp.escape(substr_old), 'g'), substr_new.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$'));
```

Demo:

```js
RegExp.escape = function(value) {
     return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

var str         = "[block $$text$$] ===";
var substr_old  = "[block $$text$$]";
var substr_new  = "[xxxxx $$text$$]";

console.log(str);

str = str.replace(RegExp(RegExp.escape(substr_old), 'g'), substr_new.replace(/\$/g, "$$$$"));

console.log(str);
```

Comment: as well as a universal solution will work? After $$ except perhaps there are other "dangerous" characters?

Comment: Only `$`. It is called dollar escaping, this is the only caveat.